# Handling decimals in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how can I add decimals to the columns of my DataTable. For example I want to show 0.00.

[image: My DataTable]

Comment: Is data comes from JS?

Comment: I am using Java on the backend

Comment: In which format/type value to show comes from backend?

Comment: The format type is Json

Answer (score 2):

Use `toFixed` method:

```js
console.log( (500).toFixed(2) )
console.log( (500.5678).toFixed(2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 500,
numberLength = number.length,
newLength = parseInt((numberLength + 2), 10),
number = number.toPrecision(newLength);
```

This will add 2 decimal places to the end of each number...

or you can do:

```
var number = 500,
newNumber = number + ".00";
```

Comment: This is my code:
`jQuery('#cuentas').DataTable( {
    data: datos.data,
    "columns": [
     { "data": "codProducto" },
     { "data": "codCuenta" },
     { "data": "nomProducto" },
     { "data": "valSaldo"},
     { "data": "valEfectivo" },
     { "data": "valCheques" },
     { "data": "valBloqueado" }
    ],
    language: {
     url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json'
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
   } );`